# A way to effectively remove outliers from a big array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

So in my software that I am developing, at some point, I have a big array of around 250 elements. I am taking the average of those elements to obtain one mean value. The problem is I have outliers in this big array at the beginning and at the end. So for instance the array could be:

```
A = [150 200 250 300 1100 1106 1130 1132 1120 1125 1122 1121 1115 2100 2500 2400 2300]
```

So in this case I would like to remove `150 200 250 300 2100 2500 2400 2300` from the array...

I know I could set those indexes to zero but however, I need a way to automatically program the software to remove those outliers no matter how many there are at the start or and at the end.

Can anyone suggest a robust way of removing those outliers?

Comment: The problem is _defining_ what an outlier is

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
A(A>(mean(A)-std(A)) & A<(mean(A)+std(A)))
> ans = 1100 1106 1130 1132 1120 1125 1122 1121 1115
```

Comment: Thank you... Actually I did try this approach but unfortunately in some cases, not all the outliers are being removed.

Comment: The right question you need to answer is: what is an outlier? This depends on your data

Answer (score 1):

Normally a robust estimator works better with outliers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics). The estimated mean and std will change a lot if the outliers are very large. I prefer to use the median and the median absolute deviation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation).

`med = median(A)
mad = median(abs(med-A))
out = (A <med - 3*mad) | (A > med + 3*mad)
A[out] = []`

It depends too a lot in what your data represents and how the distribution looks (hist(A)). For example, if your data is skewed to large values you could remove the top 0.95 of the values or something similar. Sometimes do a transformation to make the distribution resemble a normal-distribution works better. For example if the distribution is skewed to the right use a log-transform.

Answer (score -1):

I use a referral approach in this case. I can pick up e.g. 15 elements from a middle of the array, calculate average/median and than compare it to std or diff(A(end-1:end)). Actually try to use median instead of mean.